# git committed but not pushed - cannot find the files in branch, where are they?

Tags: git

I thought I was on the latest commit of my branch.  I moved my code to my local folder, and added and committed them.

When I tried to push the new files, I got the following error:

> fatal: You are not currently on a branch.

and I realized I had one of the older commits I specifically checked out.

In my lack of understanding of whatever I was doing, I ended up accidentally recloning the original branch.  My files are gone.

Can I find them, or are they literally gone?  The commit went through, but git log is not showing anything, and the commit ID I thought I was working with is showing nothing.

I don't know very much about git, so here's all I do:

> git clone -b branch_name git@gitserver.url.com:code.git

and then add, commit, and push changes.

In this case, I checked out a specific commit ID, and added and committed while I had it checked out.  But that commit is not showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you were working in a detached HEAD state, which would explain the error message about not being on any branch.  The commits you made should still be visible in the reflog, so first try:

```
git reflog
```

See if you can recognize the latest commit you made while not on a branch.  The fix here might be to checkout that commit, again in the detached HEAD state, and then create a bona fide branch, e.g.

```
git checkout S8dk2K8W        # replace S8dk2K8W with actual commit hash
git checkout -b your_branch
git push origin your_branch
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried git reflog, and it only shows the one (latest) official commit made my someone else.  My consolation is that IntelliJ keeps backups of all code I worked on, so at least I didn't lose the actual code.  Time to read up on detached HEAD state and how to avoid this in the future!

Comment: Strange.  Commits don't usually disappear like this.  My answer should have worked (I think).